# Triggering Zapier on new Shopify order containing a specific product

Tags: shopify, zapier

I have a simple Zap that is triggered on a Shopify New Order (with line details) and then creates a new account in a system called Trainerize. Works perfectly, but it is triggered by ANY new Shopify order. I need to trigger the Zap for a specific product in the Shopify order. Is this possible in Zapier, and how would I go about it? It seems you can't talk to Zapier support unless you have a plan, and I don't want a plan if it is not possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The exact implementation depends on how you want to identify the specific product. I am listing 2 possible ways

In case, the criteria to identify product is quite simple, you can use **Filter by Zap**. For example, if you want to identify product by product Id, you can just add a Filter by Zap and add the following conditions.

```
Line Items Product ID | Text Contains | Your Product ID - 12345
```

[image: Filter by Zap]

If you have some complex matching condition for your Product, you can also use **Code by Zapier** to run JavaScript code. To do so, pass the required data as input to code and return output that can be used later to see if the match was found. A simple example that gets LineItems productIds as input.

```
const TARGET_PRODUCT_ID = 12345;

const productIds = inputData.productIds.split(",");

output = {targetProductFound: false};

productIds.forEach(id => {
   // Add more conditions if needed
   if(Number(id) === TARGET_PRODUCT_ID){
     output.targetProductFound = true;
   }
});

return output
```

Then use **Filter** to proceed or abort.

[image]